# Use image hash instead of tag in pod definition

Tags: kubernetes

I am troubleshooting some errors on one of my cronjobs and I would like to make sure that the right image is being used by the pods. Is it possible to specify the image using the hash instead of the `repo/name:tag` syntax?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Docker is (in most cases) the one responsible of image fetching, you can do as stated in their [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/pull/#pull-an-image-by-digest-immutable-identifier) - `<repo>/<name>@sha256:<sha256>`.

For example, if we'd like to use the image of Ubuntu with the SHA256 digest of 45b23dee08af5e43a7fea6c4cf9c25ccf269ee113168c19722f87876677c5cb2, it would look something like `ubuntu@sha256:45b23dee08af5e43a7fea6c4cf9c25ccf269ee113168c19722f87876677c5cb2`

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/images/):

> The `image` property of a container supports the same syntax as the `docker` command does, including private registries and tags.

Which means it allows you to pull a hash based on the docker syntax for pulling a hash:

```sh
docker pull $DOCKER_REGISTRY/$NAMESPACE/$APP_NAME:$SHA1
```